# Difference between $E[X^2]$ and $E[X^3]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Hope to ask a dumb question.

$Y = aX$,with $a \in N_+$. Here, we know the correlation coefficient is 1.

Now, suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$.

1. Here, we know $X, Y$ are not independent.
2. Cov($X,Y$) = $E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = aE[X^2] = a$ So, $X,Y$ are correlated.

Now, suppose $Y = aX^2$. Others remain the same.

1. Here, we know $X,Y$ are not independent.
2. Cov($X,Y$) = $E[X^3] = 0$

I am confused about both case, the upper one is correlated but the lower one is not.
How do I see it from an intuitive way?

Comment: Why is $Cov(X,Y)=1$? Shouldn't it be $a$?

Comment: To summarize, **IF** some random variables are independent **THEN** their covariance is zero, but the inverse implication is false without some supplementary hypothesis.

Comment: If you run through the algebra, I believe that $Cov(X, Y) = a Var(X)$. However, as $Var(Y) = a^2 Var(X)$ means that $\sigma_Y = a\sigma_X$ so the correlation coefficient $\large\rho = \frac{a Var(X)}{\sigma_x\cdot a\sigma_x} = 1$ which is what the OP meant, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) may have many meanings, but from the question, you are using the specific definition of the [Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient). You are calling variables "correlated" when $\rho \neq 0$. That is solely when $\textrm{Cov}(X, Y) \neq 0$.

In the case of $Y = aX$, regardless of how $X$ is distributed, we can state the following:
$$
\begin{align}
Y &= aX\\
E(Y) &= aE(X)\\
E(XY) &= E(aX^2) = aE(X^2)\\
E(X)E(Y) &= E(X)E(aX) = aE(X)^2\\
\end{align}
$$

So
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{Cov}(X, Y) &= E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)\\
&= aE(X^2) - aE(X)^2\\
&= a\left(E(X^2) - E(X)^2\right)\\
&= a\textrm{Var}(X)
\end{align}
$$

Now $\textrm{Var}(Y) = \textrm{Var}(aX) = a^2\textrm{Var}(X)$ so $\sigma_Y = a\sigma_X$. This makes:
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{X,Y} &= \frac{\textrm{Cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\\
&=\frac{a\sigma^2_X}{\sigma_X a\sigma_X}\\
&= 1
\end{align}
$$

So the variables are perfectly correlated. Now define $Y = aX^2$. Run through the same algebra:
$$
\begin{align}
Y &= aX^2\\
E(Y) &= aE(X^2)\\
E(XY) &= E(aX^3) = aE(X^3)\\
E(X)E(Y) &= E(X)E(aX^2) = aE(X)E(X^2)\\
\textrm{Cov}(X, Y) &= E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)\\
&= aE(X^3) - aE(X)E(X^2)\\
&= a\left[E(X^3) - E(X)E(X^2)\right]
\end{align}
$$
In general, I'm not sure we can say anything about the relationship between the two variables. However, we do happen to know the moments of the standard normal. In specific:
$$
\begin{align}
E(X) &= 0\\
E(X^2) &= 1 \textrm{ Since Var}(X) = 1 \textrm{ and } \mu = 0\\
E(X^3) &= 0 \textrm{ Since skewness of normal is } 0
\end{align}
$$

So
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{Cov}(X, Y) &= E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)\\
&= a\left[E(X^3) - E(X)E(X^2)\right]\\
&= a\left[0 - 0\times 1\right] = 0
\end{align}
$$

As for intuition, perhaps the following. When $Y = aX$, graphing $Y$ against $X$ is a straight line; $X$ completely determines $Y$. However, when  $Y = aX^2$, you have a parabola with the y-axis as the line of symmetry. $X$ no longer completely determines $Y$, as there is an $X$ of equal magnitude and opposite sign that can generate the same $Y$. The fact that it is equal and opposite may be the intuitive reason for the correlation to be 0, but the algebra is primary (if not only) reason.

Answer (score 2):

$Var(X)=E[X^2]$ is the variance (measures spread around mean), which for a standard normal distribution is $1$.

$E[X^3]$ measures the skewness of the density and since a normal distribution is symmetric the skewness is $0$.

Comment: Why "$E[X^3]$ measures the symmetry of the density "?  thx,

Comment: To be more precise $E[(X^3-\mu)/\sigma]$ is a measure of the skewness (where $\mu$ is mean $\sigma$ is standard deviation)  and when this is zero then the distribution is symmetric. Hence $E[X^2]$ and $E[X^3]$ measure different things. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson.27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness

Comment: $E(X^3)$ is the skewness of a standard normal, true, but here we are talking about the correlation between two random variables, $X$ and $Y = aX^2$.

Comment: Agreed. I guess I was answering the question what is the difference between $E[X^2]$ and $E[X^3]$ rather than the relationship between $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the first case. What is your problem here?

But to the second one:

If two random variables are uncorrelated (i.e. covariance is zero), they are not necessarily independent. The example you have is the standard example to demonstrate this.
Only if $X$ and $Y$ have a joint bivariate normal distribution, from $cov(X,Y)=0$
follows that they are independent.

[For more see for example here in Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence)

Answer (score 1):

One approach to intuition is, since Y is always positive, the positiveness of X has no impact on the positiveness of Y. Therefore, X being more positive has as much impact on Y being larger than X being more negative. This is the antithesis of high correlation. I think that is all there is to it.